# Google chrome extension - toggle icon for all tabs simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, icons

I was able to toggle my extension icon for a single active tab before:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    active_tab=tab.id;
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:active_tab});
  }
});
```

But how do I change that icon for all tabs at once... including the new tabs?

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this by not supplying a `tabId` property on the Object you pass to [`browserAction.setIcon()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon). The [documentation for `tabId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#property-details-tabId) states that it is *optional* and that if specified it:

> **Limits the change to when a particular tab is selected.** Automatically resets when the tab is closed.

If you don't supply `tabId`, then what you specify for [`path`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#property-details-path) or [`imageData`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#property-details-imageData) applies to all tabs. This is the standard way that the methods of `browserAction`, which change the properties of the button, work.

Thus, in your case it would be:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    active_tab=tab.id;
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png"});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png"});
  }
});
```

Comment: lol, I just figured it out myself... but yeah it's much better this way

Comment: Once `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` is called with parameter `tabId:`, a call of `.setIcon` without `tabId:` won't change the icon on such tab. Is there a way to **reset** state of such tab to be back synchronized with default settings, so a call of `.setIcon` without `tabId:` will change its icon as well? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding another listener that activates on switching tabs.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(toggle){
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
    }
    else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tab) {
    if(toggle){
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
    }
    else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    }
});
```